# Virtualbox - SOAP FAULT: [SOAP-ENV:Server] phpvirtualbox unable to connect

Tags: php, soap, virtual-machine, virtualbox

So im reinstalling my dev box and wanted to try the virtualbox route.

The guides seem straight forward installing on ubuntu 14.04 headless server with phpvirtualbox but i keep getting stuck this error

When i go to my phpvirtualbox page and try logging in i see this error

```
Could not connect to host (http://127.0.0.1:18083/)

Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => Could not connect to host (http://127.0.0.1:18083/)
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 64
    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/phpvirtualbox/lib/ajax.php
    [line:protected] => 123
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

when i check lsof -i:18083 on the box i see the ports open and listening

```
vboxwebsr 27978 developer    9u  IPv6  50182      0t0  TCP localhost:18083 (LISTEN)
```

it also shows its running under the developer user

```
27982 developer  20   0  481M 11996  9516 S  0.0  0.6  0:00.00 /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxwebsrv -b
```

my virtual box config is as followed

```
VBOXWEB_USER=developer
VBOXWEB_HOST=127.0.0.1
VBOXWEB_PORT=18083
```

my phpvirtualbox config is as followed

```
/* Username / Password for system user that runs VirtualBox */
var $username = 'developer';
var $password = '*********';
/* SOAP URL of vboxwebsrv (not phpVirtualBox's URL) */
var $location = 'http://127.0.0.1:18083/';
```

also php runs soap

```
soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
```

To me all them configs match up as described in the virtualbox install process of making sure you run virtualbox under a specific user and specify that user in the config, the ports open and listening yet the phpvirtualbox interface can't connect, im fully able to manage and access virtualbox from the command line.

If someone could help me understand where im going wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if SELinux is blocking.

I had the same error and it was SELinux keeping phpVirtual box from connecting to the VBox Web service.

Comment: This should be a comment (once you have [enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to add one) instead of an answer. Please refer to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to learn how to earn reputation and therefore be able to comment.

Answer (score 0):

in config.php
change the location
`var $location = 'http://127.0.0.1:18083/';`
to
`var $location = 'http://localhost:18083/';`

I don't know why, maybe something wrong in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running `selinux`, this step my be necessary:

`semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 18083`

Comment: Hi @alden and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please edit your question to be grammatically correct, punctuated, and use Markdown formatting.